# Filters Multiple values directly on report

Tags: reporting-services

I wanted to instead of defining the parameter in the query but use the filter to work as parameters. 
I have configured SSRS filter expression like

The parameter is called "Locations" and i am allowing multiple values
  From the datasets: The field is called Location
  Filter from the dataset

- Expression:[LOCATION]
- Operator: IN (i tried Like)
- Value =Parameters!Location.Value(0)

When i run, it works when i pick one item from my drop down option. But when i pick more than 1 location  i get values of the first value picked from the drop down only. It doesn't recognize the multiple choice.

Answer (score 0):

You have enabled the multiple parameter, so you could use expression like below to see whether it works or not(it will recognize all parameters)

Expression:[LOCATION]
Operator: IN 
Value =Parameters!Location.Value

Zoe